# programatically search a place in google map API by passing place name

Tags: google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I want to pass a place name in google map api and using that I need to extract description of that place which I get left side in gogle map.This should be done programatically i.e I have a list of place in database and I'll pass those data to API and need to get type.If I pass KFC then I need to extract "Chicken Restaurant" keyword from its output,I am not sure is it possible or not! If its possible then  the output would be in which format, XML or some other??

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not a website to ask others to code for you. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help.

Comment: I m not asking code,I just need to know is it possible or not..

Comment: Did you read documentation? Have you tried anything? You should do so, then come here and ask if you have a specific question or issue with something. Your question is too broad/vague and off-topic.

Comment: You actually want to use Google Place API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using JSON

```
<?php
function geoPlaceID($location)
{
   $locationclean = str_replace (" ", "+", $location);
   $details_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . $locationclean . "&key=YOUR_KEY";
   $du = file_get_contents($details_url);

   $getDetails = json_decode(utf8_encode($du),true);
   if ($getDetails['status']=="OK")
   {
       $a=$getDetails['results'][1]['types'];
       print_r($a);
      // echo implode(" ",$a)."<br>";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Place ID not found";
   }
}
geoPlaceID("kfc");
 ?>
```

using XML

```
<?php

function place_ID($location)
{
$locationclean = str_replace (" ", "+", $location);
$data = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=" . $locationclean . "&key=YOUR_KEY";

$xml = file_get_contents($data);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml->result->type as $key => $value){
    $location_id = $value;
    echo $location_id;
    echo "<br>";
}
}
place_ID("kfc");

?>
```